# Scala function return behaviour

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm trying to solve this epfl scala course homework where they ask me to write the sum of a list. I can do it if I use return statements or if use match statement but I can't understand why it wouldn't work using if/else without return statement.

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs {
  if (xs.isEmpty) {
    0
  } else {
    xs.head + sum(xs.tail)
  }
}
```

The run time error that I get when I run sum(List(1,3,2)) is

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.apply$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:89)
  at example.Lists$.sum(Lists.scala:39)
  at example.Lists$.sum(Lists.scala:39)
  at example.Lists$.sum(Lists.scala:39)
  at example.Lists$.sum(Lists.scala:39)
```

If I replace 0 in the code with 100 the error message changes to java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 100 . It's like it is trying to access the N'th element of the list and all I need is a return. If I add the two return statements all works as expected.

Can you please shed some light ?

Comment: Try removing `xs` after the `=` in the start of your function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause is in the first line of the function declaration:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs {
```

This is equivalent with:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.apply(<Some function>)
```

For example `xs.apply(3)` means get item with index 3 from the list `xs`.

Scala will evaluate the code inside the brackets and will try to apply the result to `xs`. As it unwinds the recursion, it will eventually get to an empty list, but the program is asking it to return `xs(0)` which does not exist thus the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

To make this program do what you intend it to do, just remove the `xs` from the beginning of your function body:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
```

Now:

```
sum(List(1,3,2))
res0: Int = 6
```

Comment: Also, if the entire body of the method is a single expression, there is no need to create a statement block. Just lose the curly braces. The same applies to the conditional expression: `def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = if (xs.isEmpty) 0 else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)`